# Django: latest record for each value of another field

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

Let us say we have a `TemperatureForecast` model (see below for a Django definition). A forecaster will produce many forecasts of the same target period (say `2021-01-01 6AM UTC`), because it will forecast the temperature for that period again and again (at `2020-12-31 8PM UTC`, at `2020-12-31 9PM UTC` and so on).

Now say we would like to know the "latest" (to be defined after the model definition) temperature forecast, by a given forecaster, for each hour from `2021-01-01 1AM` to `2021-01-01 10AM`. That is, I need to retrieve the "latest" record for each target datetime. In this example, we would have (at most) 10 records.

The Django model (with Postgres backend) would look as follows:

```py
from django.db import models
from .forecaster import Forecaster

class TemperatureForecast(models.Model):
    forecaster = models.ForeignKey(Forecaster, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    temperature_in_c = models.FloatField()
    forecast_datetime = models.DateTimeField()
    forecast_time_delta_in_s = models.IntegerField()

    # the time of creation of the record
    # not the time of the forecast was actually made
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

`forecast_datetime` is the field we would like to group by and `forecast_time_delta_in_s` is the field we would to minimize by ("latest" means `min(forecast_time_delta_in_s)`). (Assuming `created_at` was reliable, `forecast_time_delta_in_s` can be thought of as `forecast_datetime - created_at`. But `created_at` cannot be relied on.)

Ideally we would retrieve a Django QuerySet of `TemperatureForecast` but fetching a QuerySet with values is fine as well, as long `forecast_time_delta_in_s`, `temperature_in_c` and `forecast_datetime` are all present.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46446684/timestamp-trunchour-aggregation-in-django) might help with grouping results by hour

Answer (score 0):

Looks like we can simply

```py
forecasts = TemperatureForecast.objects.filter(
    forecaster=forecaster,
    forecast_datetime__gte=datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 1),
    forecast_datetime__lte=datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 10)
).order_by(
    'forecast_datetime', 
    'forecast_time_delta_in_s'
).distinct('forecast_datetime')
```